# Big Calendar Multiple Events Timeline

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use react-big-calendar to display my events. The problem is all events display on top of the calendar not the the time slot due to the event spans multiple dates. How to make the event in the correct time slot 3pm - 5pm instead of on the top in week view? My sandbox is [here](https://3m8sv.csb.app/) or https://3m8sv.csb.app/

Comment: Do you want to create an event that starts at 3PM and ends at 5PM for a given range of dates? In that case, I'm afraid you have to create a separate event for each day.

Comment: If, however, you simply want to fill all the hours between the start and end date, you have to pass a [`showMultiDayTimes`](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#prop-showMultiDayTimes) prop to your `Calendar` component.

Comment: Yeah, I want to show the event from 3pm-5pm for a given range of dates. Maybe I need to loop through the dates to display the events. :(